# Need some advice on data analysis

Tags: dataset

I collected data from 500 participants. Here's an example of the data:

Response 1:
Age: 25
Gender: Male
Choice 1: 1
Choice 2: 1
Choice 3: 0
Choice 4: 1
Choice 5: 1
... Up to choice 30

Response 2:
Age: 20
Gender: Female
Choice 1: 1
Choice 2: 1
Choice 3: 0
Choice 4: 1
Choice 5: 1
...

All questions were categorical and the choices were binary outcomes.

My goal:
a) To see what choices were preferred in general (using the mean, since the data is normal)
b) Does gender make a difference in choice (using linear regression)

What I really want advice on:
1) I put in control variables and it shows a preference for choice 1 by about 3%. What should I do to correct this to make it 50/50? Or should I even do that at all?
2) There are responses to the survey where participants just selected 1 for all responses. Should I reject these?

Thank you!

Comment: The data are *not* normal: apart from the ages, they are *binomial* (which is about as non-normal as one can get). Any reasonable measure of binary results will be equivalent to the mean, so you don't really have any choice in that matter.  What exactly do you mean by "controls"? Your mention of that raises questions concerning what ought to be compared to what and what it means for something to be "preferred": are you comparing choices to each other or are you comparing experimental subjects to controls for each of the choices?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I have limited knowledge of statistics, so that was helpful. On the survey, there was a question asked twice. The means don't match up for the question, there's a difference of 3-5%. If the difference is greater than the variance, should the data be adjusted in any way? And yes, I'm comparing experimental subjects to choices and also the response on one choice to another.